# ImportError: cannot import name 'transpose'

Tags: python, conda, transpose

I try to run a script which starts like this:
**import os, sys, subprocess, argparse, random, transposer, numpy, csv, scipy, gzip**

BUT, I got this error:
**ImportError: cannot import name 'transpose'**

I work on slurm cluster. Should I install transposer? I work with conda as we don't have permission to install on cluster. But, there is no conda env for that.
Would you please help on this? Thanks

Comment: `conda install pip` will give you a pip to work with for that active conda environment

Comment: That's an old package (Python 2 only) with no maintenance for several years. I would be rather surprised if this functionality isn't implemented in more well-supported packages. I.e., consider updating the code.

Answer (score 0):

pip install transposer ? worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).